# Laravel Notification doesn't work when queued

Tags: laravel, queue

I'm using notifications to send emails to the admin when a new note added by the user.  If I don't use the ShouldQueue, all work fine.. When I use queue I got an error

ErrorException: Undefined property: App\Notifications\NewKidNote::$note

what might be the reason?
here is my notification code

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use App\Models\KidNote;

class NewKidNote extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $note;
    protected $kidname;
    protected $userfullname;
    protected $color;
    protected $sentnote;
    protected $kidid;

    public function __construct($note)
    {
        $this->note          = $note;
        $this->kidname       = $note->kid->name;
        $this->userfullname  = $note->user->fullname;
        $this->color         = $note->color;
        $this->sentnote      = $note->note;
        $this->kidid         = $note->kid_id;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail','database'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
              ->subject('New Note added')
              ->greeting('Hello ')
              ->line('New Note has been added for '. $this->kidname. ' by '.$this->userfullname)
              ->line('Note Color: '.$this->color)
              ->line('Note')
              ->line($this->sentnote)
              ->action('You can also see the note here', route('admin.children.show',$this->kidid));
    }
    
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
           'icon'    => 'notepad',
           'color'   => $this->color,
           'message' => 'New note added for '. $this->kidname ,
           'link'    => route('admin.children.show',$this->kidid)
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call this Event? Show it please. And why yo need this->node = $node ? Nowhere you se it

Comment: $admin->notify(new NewKidNote($note));
this is how i call it.

Comment: Why do you need `$this->node = $node`? You sets node models all data to your notification class properties

Comment: i was using that before i implemented shouldqueue.. it doesn't cause any problem I used it without that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to self.. Make sure you clean the cache and restart the queue :)) then it works fine!! This code runs perfectly. thanks

Comment: I m glad i put it up here :)) i m back to my own question and answer

Comment: I have run into this same problem. Which queue is used and how do I restart it?

Comment: if you could, it would be great if you went through all the steps you did to get this to work. The docs say that all I have to do is add the trait but I ran into the `ErrorException: Undefined property: App\Notifications\` problem.

Comment: this is for local environment. If you are running the queue worker in the local terminal, first close that terminal ( meaning stop the queue worker ) then open another terminal, go to your application folder and run this command .. php artisan optimize:clear ... after that start your queue again. ( php artisan queue:work ) whenever you make changes to your notification files you need to restart the queue again